# Left joining with one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have a SQL Server query that looks like this:

```
SELECT  ListingId, hh.DateAltered
FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        h.ParentId, 
        h.DateAltered 
    FROM 
        History AS h
    WHERE h.ParentType = 'Listing' 
) hh 
ON hh.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
WHERE ListingId = 56082
```

So basically I have two tables, `Listings` and `History`. The `Listings` table only has 1 row. The `History` table has 5 rows which are linked to the `Listings` table record (as you can tell from the `LEFT JOIN`).

When I run the above query then it returns 5 rows. This is because the `History` table has 5 rows that are linked to the 1 row in the `Listings` table.

```
ListingId   DateAltered
56082   2013-11-06 09:27:29.647
56082   2013-11-08 14:30:42.543
56082   2013-11-08 15:11:30.390
56082   2013-11-14 09:54:21.060
56082   2014-01-09 16:23:52.440
```

But I only need 1 row from the `History` table, so I can see what the last `DateAltered` is.

So I thought it would be as easy as adding a `TOP(1)` to the `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
SELECT  ListingId, hh.DateAltered
FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP(1)
        h.ParentId, 
        h.DateAltered 
    FROM 
        History AS h
    WHERE h.ParentType = 'Listing' 
) hh 
ON hh.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
WHERE ListingId = 56082
```

It does return 1 row now (which is what I want), but now the `DateAltered` column is `NULL`:

```
ListingId   DateAltered
56082           NULL
```

Why is this happening? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `MIN(DateAltered)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because the `top 1` record you have selected doesn't have the same ID as your listings table.

You want the most recent record from the history table, where the ID matches. You can get this using `row_number`

```
SELECT  ListingId, hh.DateAltered
FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    select * 
    from 
    (
        SELECT 
            h.ParentId, 
            h.DateAltered,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by parentid order by datealtered desc) rn
        FROM 
            History AS h
        WHERE h.ParentType = 'Listing' 
    ) h
    where rn=1
) hh 
ON hh.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
WHERE ListingId = 56082
```

Comment: this is a good solution if you need more columns from the history with maximum datealtered. however in this case it seems that a simple max/groupby will suffice as only the grouped (maxed) value is required

Comment: @BrettSchneider I agree

Answer (score 1):

if you want last `DateAltered` value, you should use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  ListingId, hh.DateAltered
FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        h.ParentId, 
        MAX(h.DateAltered) AS DateAltered
    FROM 
        History AS h
    WHERE h.ParentType = 'Listing' 
    GROUP BY h.ParentId
) hh 
ON hh.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
WHERE ListingId = 56082
```

Answer (score 0):

you are joining with only one line from history where you do not know whether it has a matching parentid. you can put the top (1) in the main query and sort it by datealtered.

```
SELECT TOP(1) ListingId, hh.DateAltered
FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        h.ParentId, 
        h.DateAltered 
    FROM 
        History AS h
    WHERE h.ParentType = 'Listing' 
) hh 
ON hh.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
WHERE ListingId = 56082
order by hh.DateAltered desc
```

however my suggestion would be to do this:

```
SELECT l.ListingId
     , max(hh.DateAltered) as DateAltered
  FROM Listings (NOLOCK) l
  left join
       History AS hh
    ON hh.ParentId = l.ListingId
   and hh.ParentType = 'Listing'
 WHERE l.ListingId = 56082
 group by
       l.ListingId
```

which is giving you the maximum datealtered per listingid.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a subquery and return a value as a column
something like

```
SELECT  ListingId, 
        (SELECT max(h.DateAltered) 
         FROM  History AS h
         WHERE h.ParentId = Listings.ListingId
                and h.ParentType = 'Listing') as LatestDateAltered

FROM Listings (NOLOCK)
WHERE ListingId = 56082
```